# How do we express $(e, \pi)$ as unions of open intervals with rational endpoints?

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

One of the definition of basis of a topology is that any open set can be expressed as unions of basis, but I always thought the other definition was easier to use. So for this definition, how do we express $(e, \pi)$ as unions of open intervals with rational endpoints which forms a basis for the usual topology for R.

Comment: Just take $(e, \pi) = \bigcup_{\substack{q_1,q_2 \in \mathbb{Q} \\ e < q_1, q_2 < \pi}} (q_1, q_2)$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no real problem: consider the sets $A=\{a\in\mathbb{Q}:e<a<(e+\pi)/2\}$ and $B=\{b\in\mathbb{Q}:(e+\pi)/2<b<\pi\}$
Then
$$
(e,\pi)=\bigcup_{\substack{a\in A \\ b\in B}}(a,b)
$$
Clearly the union is contained in $(e,\pi)$. The infimum $m$ of the union has to be $e$, otherwise there would be $r\in\mathbb{Q}$ such that $e<r<m$ (between any two real numbers there is at least one rational number). This contradicts $m$ to be the infimum, because $r\in A$.

Similarly, the supremum of the union is $\pi$ and so the union is the whole $(e,\pi)$.

We used no particular property of $e$ and $\pi$: indeed the same argument proves that *any* open interval is the union of open intervals with rational extremes.

Answer (score 3):

Just pick any pair of sequences of rationals, one approaching $\pi$ from below and the other approaching $e$ from above, and use those as the endpoints of your intervals. For example, $$(2.8\,,\,3.1)$$ $$(2.72\,\,\,,\,\, 3.14)$$ $$(2.719\quad, \quad 3.141)$$ $$\mbox{etc.}$$ will do the trick.

More generally, for **any** pair of reals $a<b$, we always have $$(a,b)=\bigcup_{x,y\in\mathbb{Q}, a<x<y<b}(x,y).$$ (Note that unlike the above, this representation isn't naturally a simple sequence of intervals; we've avoided the need to make a particular choice of converging sequences here at the cost of a less convenient overall form of the set of intervals involved.)

Answer (score 0):

using
$$\pi = 3.141592...$$
$$3 - e = 0.281718...$$

$(e, \pi) = (3 - 0.2, 3.1) \cup (3 - 0.28, 3.14)  \cup (3 - 0.281, 3.141)\cup \cdots $